# With Devtools on Firefox and JSBin: Some files don't want to load with devtools closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, greasemonkey

My script will put a highly customized version of CKeditor on the target site, right now I'm configuring CkEditor to my taste and I use JS bin to build my script before testing it on the target site.

What happen now is that my custom configuation of Ckeditor (CkMikeConfig.js) is Only loaded when the devtools are "open" in Firefox.

If I close the devtools panel CkEditor for a strange reason don't find my custom file and load the default file instead. :(

Screenshot with devtools open:
[image]

Screenshot with devtools closed: 
[image]

Here's the URL of the JSbin: http://jsbin.com/cerajezota/2/edit?html,output

I don't understand why it react differently with devtools open or closed ???

Comment: TLDR.  But it's most likely a timing issue.  Try adding delays, timers, mutation observers, and/or `waitForKeyElements`.

Comment: Also try debugging the script when the devpanel is closed by using lots of console.log, then see what's printed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of my problem: It was a **Firefox issue** even if it the page have been "Hard Refreshed" to remove the cache it was loading an old buggy config file when I was not using the devtools.

**Solution:** Using this addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/clear-site-cache/ to clear the Firefox cache.

**N.B.:** It's a well know bug  from Mozilla that I did not encounter before, just hoping it will be fixed one of those day but I don't hold my breath.